# Axis2 is not working properly

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, soap, apache-axis

When I try to access **Services**, **Validate** and **Administration** link on the URL `http://localhost:82/SOAPDemo/`, where my Axis2 Web Application is deployed, it gives me the following error :

`Servlet.init() for servlet AxisServlet threw exception`

At the back-end,  while apache tomcat 7 is being started in eclipse, it shows me the following warning :

`[WARN] Unable to instantiate deployer org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer;`

Comment: Please update your question to include the Axis2 version number and check if there are other, more specific error messages in the logs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved this by adding axis2-jaxws.jar in the classpath.
You can integrate it with maven : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2-jaxws

Comment: THX Pierre, that's what the problem solves  ... : D
I test it with AXIS2 1.7.4   

`WEB-INF/lib/axis2-adb-1.7.4.jar
WEB-INF/lib/axis2-jaxws-1.7.4.jar
WEB-INF/lib/axis2-kernel-1.7.4.jar
WEB-INF/lib/axis2-metadata-1.7.4.jar
WEB-INF/lib/axis2-saaj-1.7.4.jar
WEB-INF/lib/axis2-spring-1.7.4.jar
WEB-INF/lib/axis2-transport-base-1.7.4.jar
WEB-INF/lib/axis2-transport-http-1.7.4.jar
WEB-INF/lib/axis2-transport-local-1.7.4.jar
WEB-INF/lib/axis2-transport-tcp-1.7.4.jar`

Comment: I used to see this warning but once i added the axis2-Jaxws jar i don't see the warning anymore. Can you let me know why this has happened? what does the jar do to remove the warning?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when I use axis2 1.7.9, then I tried to follow

- "I solved this by adding axis2-jaxws.jar in the classpath. You can integrate it with maven : [http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2-jaxws"](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2-jaxws%22), solution by Pierre-Yves Le Dévéhat

But it didn't work. Then I tried the

- "I probably hit the same issue, here is the call stack:" ->
- "I fixed it with old axis2 1.6.4 instead of 1.7.1 installation and new project creation", solution by user6140506, edited by TeWu

then the error is fixed.

axis2 1.6.4 is working for me...

Answer (score -1):

I probably hit the same issue, here is the call stack:

```
[WARN] Unable to instantiate deployer org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer; see debug logs for more details
avr. 28, 2016 6:27:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/resolver/URIResolver
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:61)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4996)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
    ... 24 more
```

I fixed it with old axis2 1.6.4 instead of 1.7.1 installation and new project creation

Comment: This does not look like an answer to the question.

Comment: @Nimesh: that's impossible to know because the OP didn't provide more information...

Comment: @AndreasVeithen It was not an answer at all when I posted the comment. The last line for the solution was added later on.